# ASP.NET Switch database during program run

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I have 2 Mongo Databases. I wold like to switch to Database1 when UserRole is "Admin1" and switch to Database2 when UserRole is "Admin2". Is this possible?

```
private CreatorDBClient()
{
    _client = new MongoClient();
   
//Here i would like to have something like
//IF User.IsInRole("Admin1")  then  _databaseName = "NextProduction1";
//ELSE                              _databaseName = "NextProduction2"

    _defaultCompanyCollection = "Companies";
    _database = _client.GetDatabase(_databaseName);     
    _companyCollection = _database.GetCollection<CompanyModel>(_defaultCompanyCollection);
}

public static CreatorDBClient GetInstance()
{
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        _instance = new CreatorDBClient();
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create follow class.

```
public class HttpContextValues
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; }
    public HttpContextValues()
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
        HttpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public class HttpContextValues
   {
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; }
    public HttpContextValues()
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
        HttpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }


    public IEnumerable<dynamic> UserRoles()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User.Claims.Count() > 0)
        {
            var result = HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == 
            ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Usage

```
HttpContextValues _httpContextValues = new HttpContextValues();
__httpContextValues.UserRoles();
```

Comment: It helped me! I spend 2 days on this problem. Thank you very much!!!!!!! <3

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can create two context. if role is admin1, dependicies context 1. Or you can change connection string for user-role on run time

Comment: The question is how to check UserRole in CreatorDBClient class?

Comment: Sorry. You can use HttpContext object for access to claims value.